# varnish regex or for if (bereq.url ~ "

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I try to create a regex for varnish cache v4

```
sub vcl_backend_response {


 if (bereq.url ~ "(/media|/bundles|/sonata_admin/|/build)$" ) {

{
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        set beresp.http.cache-control = "public, max-age=2592000";
        set beresp.ttl = 30d;
        return (deliver);
    }
```

also I try

```
 if (bereq.url ~ "(\/media|\/bundles|\/sonata_admin|\/build)$" ) {
```

I want to include all files where location starts from /media or /bundles or ...

this not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your config, it doesn't work because you're matching up with `$` that stands for "at the end of string".

You want to use `^` which is "match at the beginning", thus:

```cpp
if (bereq.url ~ "^/(media|bundles|sonata_admin|build)") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.http.cache-control = "public, max-age=2592000";
    set beresp.ttl = 30d;
    return (deliver);
}
```